# Slider Center Mode Styling

Tags: javascript, slider, carousel, slick.js, owl-carousel

I was wondering, has anyone encountered a slider library than can do the same styling (or maybe close) like the attached image?

[Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA4DR.jpg)

I tried using both slick and owl carousel and styled via CSS and JS but I end up messing up the sliding functionality. I've been stuck browsing all available slider/carousel libraries.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Slick.js has the option `centerMode: true` and you can style the slide widths by using JS to target the slides on either side of the current one (using `data-slick-index`), but that's not going to allow you to overlap the edges of the slides.

Comment: I will try this one. Thank you.